# PERL interpreter stopped in windows cmd

Tags: perl

I try to run certain script, but i am getting some following errors OUT OF MEMORY!.

```
$top_number = 100;
$x = 1;
$total = 0;
while ( $x <= $top_number ) {
    $total = $total + $x;   
    #$x += 1;       
}

print "The total from 1 to $top_number is $total\n";

  but my other scripts are running in windows cmd . Kindly suggest.
```

Comment: => `while ( $total <= $top_number )`

Comment: Nice name Sukhoi 27 :-)

Comment: This is an infinite loop, because $x += 1; is commented out. How long does it take until OUT OF MEMORY is reached?

Comment: @Сухой27 I tried with your folowing script, but still it is not processing and i get same OUT OF MEMORY

Comment: What is your exact error message? https://eval.in/238921

Comment: @Сухой27 the exact message is OUT OF MEMORY AND PERL INTERPRETER STOPPED WORKING . But when i run my other scripts its fine

Comment: This is windows error message, and code you've posted and fixed is probably too simplified to reproduce the problem you're encountering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$x` never changes, so `$x` is always less than or equal to `$top_number`, so the loop never ends.

But the loop doesn't allocate any memory, so the program you posted doesn't run out of memory even though something<sup>[1]</sup> claimed it was.

---

1. I don't think Perl emits the message `OUT OF MEMORY!`.